# Error loading an SDL_ttf font: strange return pointers

Tags: c, sdl, truetype

I've the following code snippet whose job is to simply produce and draw a string using the SDL_ttf library:

```
void drawString (G_Frame *frame, char *string, int x, int y, int size) {

    TTF_Font *font = NULL;
    while (font == NULL) {
        font = TTF_OpenFontRW(frame->fontMem, 0, size);
    }

    SDL_Surface *words = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, string, frame->drawColor);
    SDL_Rect dest = {x, y, words->w, words->h};
    SDL_BlitSurface(words, NULL, frame->canvas, &dest);

    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    SDL_FreeSurface(words);
}
```

Now TTF_OpenFontRW has been giving me many problems. First of all, if I don't have that while loop, the font's will get loaded properly sometimes but the function will sometimes return a null pointer for seemingly no reason. A call to TTF_GetError() says "Couldn't load font file" but that's hardly descriptive. So, as a temporary fix, I put a while loop around that until a valid pointer is returned and it seems to work.

To make things even weirder, that only happens if I fill the SDL_RWops with FreeMono.ttf font. Otherwise, if I use FreeSerif.ttf, I usually don't get a null pointer returned. Sometimes, I'm returned a pointer to a font with no meaningful data. Upon creating a surface from such a font, I get a segmentation fault and TTF_GetError() saying that the font has no width.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: As a side not, I have checked that the SDL_RWops pointer is valid and in every case is has been. Besides, once I load it with the font file, I never touch it again.

Comment: You should probably not be reloading the font every single time you try to draw text, but that's besides the point. How do you create the RWOps in `frame->fontMem`? Also, looking into the source code it doesn't look like sdl_ttf ever seeks to a particular position in the RWOps you give it, so maybe you should make sure to seek to 0 before attempting to load the font? Just a thought, I've not had these issues myself.

Comment: Wow! That did it, the seeking to 0 at the RWops. I can't believe that the library wouldn't have that build in. Thanks for the suggestion! Edit: From the documentation, it seems that the library assumes the close_rwops_after_use flag to be set so that would somewhat explain it. Still bad choice if you ask me.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense if you think about it. Say, for instance, instead of a single font your RWOps contains an array of fonts (not likely if you're reading from a file, but maybe you're getting this from a database or a network socket). If you wanted to read for example 5 fonts from that array you'd just call `TTF_OpenFontRW` 5 times. If the ttf library did seek to 0 after reading it just couldn't do that. Also, the library doesn't assume it should close the file, that's exactly why there is a parameter for that.